# How to search group_by with association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know how I describe this question, at first I want show my model which maintaining a relation like below

category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :job_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :jobs, through: :job_categories
end
```

job.rb

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :job_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :job_categories
end
```

job_category.rb

```
class JobCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category, counter_cache: :jobs_count
  belongs_to :job
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "parent"
end
```

the `parent` is a column which maintain the group like `Technology` and under this `ruby,rails,programming` etc which is Technology related.

Below is my query for showing group by category

```
Category.select(:id, :name, :parent).group_by{|p| p.parent}
```

and it's showing like this

**Technology**

- ruby
- rails
- etc

Now I want to show all jobs in group by **Technology**, I have a query for this like

```
Job.joins(:categories).where('lower(categories.parent) LIKE lower(?)', "%#{params[:parent]}%")
```

and it's showing wrong output like if I have only one job which categories is `ruby,rails` then this one job is showing two times, one for ruby and one for rails.

Thanks

Comment: if you only need to list them in groued order why are you applying a where condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your associations are correct, you can retrieve all unique jobs for some categories by following:

```
Job.joins(:job_categories).joins(:categories).where('lower(categories.parent) LIKE lower(?)', "%#{params[:parent]}%").distinct
```

This will join the `jobs` with the intermediate table `job_categories` and `jobs` on relevant keys and `where` clause will then allow you to be selective on what you want to retrieve.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "jobs" .*
FROM "jobs" INNER
JOIN "job_categories" ON "job_categories" ."job_id" = "jobs" ."id" INNER
JOIN "job_categories" "job_categories_jobs_join" ON "job_categories_jobs_join" ."job_id" = "jobs" ."id" INNER
JOIN "categories" ON "categories" ."id" = "job_categories_jobs_join" ."category_id"
WHERE
(
 lower ( categories.parent ) LIKE lower ( "Technology" ) )
```

**Update**:
Actually, we don't need to have explicit join to `job_categories` either, the following should suffice:

```
Job.joins(:categories).where('lower(categories.parent) LIKE lower(?)', "%#{params[:parent]}%").distinct

SELECT DISTINCT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" INNER JOIN "job_categories" ON "job_categories"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "job_categories"."category_id" WHERE (lower ( categories.parent ) LIKE lower ( "Technology" ))
```

Comment: Now showing triple not double see the query from log `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jobs" INNER JOIN "job_categories" ON "job_categories"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" INNER JOIN "job_categories" "job_categories_jobs_join" ON "job_categories_jobs_join"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "job_categories_jobs_join"."category_id" WHERE (lower(categories.parent) LIKE lower('%Technology%'))`

Comment: add `.distinct` at end of relation.

Comment: `Job.joins(:job_categories).joins(:categories).where('lower(categories.parent) LIKE lower(?)', "%#{params[:parent]}%").distinct`

Comment: the benefit of this query is it _remains_ an ActiveRelation which will enable you to chain with other queries and join if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just few other options to fetch and group records with association has_many_through:

```
# Filtering by query
Job.joins(:categories).select('jobs.id, jobs.name, categories.parent').where('lower(categories.parent) LIKE lower(?)', "Technology").distinct.inspect
# => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Job id: 1, name: "Developer">, #<Job id: 2, name: "Debugger">]>

# Grouping by categories.parent, return a hash
Job.joins(:categories).select('jobs.id, jobs.name, categories.parent').all.distinct.group_by(&:parent)
# => {"Technology"=>[#<Job id: 1, name: "Developer">, #<Job id: 2, name: "Debugger">], "Mechanics"=>[#<Job id: 3, name: "Technic">]}

# Accessing the hash by key
Job.joins(:categories).select('jobs.id, jobs.name, categories.parent').all.distinct.group_by(&:parent)["Technology"]
#=> [#<Job id: 1, name: "Developer">, #<Job id: 2, name: "Debugger">]
```